# Grails GORM: How to 'null' a property of a child in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: grails, properties, nullable, one-to-many, children

I have a undirectional one to many relationship of two domain classes:

```
package net.peddn

class User {
    static hasMany = [texts: Text]
    String username 
}
```

and

```
package net.peddn

class Text {

    long creator
    String title

    static constraints = {
        creator( nullable: true )
    }   
}
```

my User controller looks like this:

```
package net.peddn

class UserController {

static scaffold = true

    def delete() {

        def userInstance = User.get(params.id)

        userInstance.texts.each { text ->
            text.creator = null
        }           

        userInstance.delete(flush: true)

}
```

my BootStrap.groovy looks like this:

```
import net.peddn.Text
import net.peddn.User

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

    User user = new User(username: "username")

    user.save(flush: true)

    Text text1 = new Text(title: "titel 1", creator: user.id)

    Text text2 = new Text(title: "titel 2", creator: user.id)

    user.addToTexts(text1)

    user.addToTexts(text2)

    user.save(flush: true)

    }

    def destroy = {
    }

}
```

When I now try to delete my User I get the following error:

```
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/usertexts
| Error 2012-06-17 19:33:49,581 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [POST] /usertexts/user/index - parameters:
id: 1
_action_delete: Löschen
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
    Line | Method
->>   21 | doCall    in net.peddn.UserController$_delete_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     19 | delete    in net.peddn.UserController
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

If i change the code to

```
text.creator = 0
```

in UserController.groovy is works perfectly.

By the way: I used this domain model because I don't want the Text objects to be deleted when a User will be deleted. But I also want to know who created the Text object. If someone has a better solution for this problem PLEASE let me know.

Thanks!
Peter

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation please try if this works:

```
    def delete() {

        def userInstance = User.get(params.id)

        userInstance.texts.each { text ->
            userInstance.removeFromTexts(text)
        }           

        userInstance.delete(flush: true)
    }
```

If you want bidirectional relation User-Texts and you don't want texts to be deleted when user is deleted you can change this behaviour. Check documentation section on cascades in Hibernate here: [custom cascades](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customCascadeBehaviour). You can change mapping like this:

```
class User {
    static hasMany = [texts: Text]

    static mapping = {
        texts cascade: "save-update"
    }
}
```

Comment: ok... your first solution throwed the same exception. then I tried your second solution with custom cascading. I tried this before with no success.

Comment: If I declare the bidirectional relation with
`static belongsTo = [user: User]`
I get a 'Referential integrity constraint violation'.
BUT if I declare it with
`static belongsTo = User`
the application shows the expected behaviour. Is this normal or is this a bug?

Comment: Sorry, even with `static belongsTo = User` I get a error. I forgot the User property in the Text class: `User user`; `static belongsTo = User` with this I get the same error...

Comment: Does `static belongsTo = [creator: User]` works? Remove `User user` from Text class.

Comment: Yeah, but then there is no reference to the User anymore... I think a child in a bidirectional relation MUST have a reference to its parent. So the only way is to make the relation unidirectional and to store the user id as normal property in the Text class. But then I ran into this error as described in my firts post.

Comment: You can't have reference to deleted User instance. Even if you store id of deleted User instance it's only a number after you delete User instance. You should consider changing your solution do desactivate users instead of deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the right [hint](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-can-I-save-null-into-database-which-the-column-is-int-td1390720.html). It seems that this is a casting problem. see:

[Groovy Primitive Type Cast Gotcha When Upgrading to Grails 2.0](http://lauripiispanen.github.com/blog/2012/02/23/groovy-primitive-type-cast-gotcha-when-upgrading-to-grails-2-dot-0/)

So i changed the primitive "long" property of the Text domain class to its "boxed" version "Long":

```
package net.peddn

class Text {

    Long creator
    String title

    static constraints = {
        creator( nullable: true )
    }   
}
```

and now the property can be set to null!

Thank you Tomasz for your help!